# Not able to select drop down list ,showing invisible

Tags: selenium, webdriver

for below code not able to select the 'Amortization' drop down

```
   import java.awt.Toolkit;    
    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public class PracticeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver;
        WebDriverWait wait;

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\dilu316\\Downloads\\selenium workspace\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");

        //approach 1 - to maximize screen in chrome
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");;
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);

        //if the below method wont work for maximizing screen then above method we can use
        //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("http://ia.ca/");

        //approach 2 - to maximize screen in chrome
        /*Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        int height = (int)toolkit.getScreenSize().getHeight();
        int width  = (int)toolkit.getScreenSize().getWidth();
        System.out.println(height + "--" + width);

        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(width, height));*/


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-secondaire']//a[@data-utag-name='loans']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Mortgages')]")).click();
        //in the upper xpath we can put a ". in place of text()" also

        //method 1 -if element is not clickable
        /*WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Calculate your payments')]")));*/

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("scroll(255, 644)");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Calculate your payments')]")).click();

        WebElement priceSlideLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slider-handle min-slider-handle custom']"));
        WebElement slideTrack = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slider-track-high']"));
        Dimension sliderSize = slideTrack.getSize();
        int sliderWidth = sliderSize.getWidth();
        int xCoord = priceSlideLocator.getLocation().getX();
        System.out.println(xCoord);
        System.out.println(sliderWidth);
        Thread.sleep(10);
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(priceSlideLocator)
        .click()
        .dragAndDropBy(priceSlideLocator, xCoord+sliderWidth,0)
        .build()
        .perform();

        WebElement hiddenPriceLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sliderPrixPropriete']"));
        int priceValue = Integer.parseInt(hiddenPriceLocator.getAttribute("value"));
        if(priceValue==2000000){
            System.out.println("price value is 2000000");
        }

        String stylePercent = priceSlideLocator.getAttribute("style");
        if(stylePercent.contains("left: 100%")){
            System.out.println("slide is 100%");
        }

        priceSlideLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slider-handle min-slider-handle custom']"));
        slideTrack = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slider-track-high']"));
        sliderSize = slideTrack.getSize();
        //sliderWidth = sliderSize.getWidth();
        xCoord = priceSlideLocator.getLocation().getX();
        System.out.println(xCoord);
        Thread.sleep(10);
        Actions builder2 = new Actions(driver);
        builder2.moveToElement(priceSlideLocator).click().dragAndDropBy(priceSlideLocator,-(xCoord+sliderWidth),0).build().perform();
        System.out.println("slide BACK%");

        hiddenPriceLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sliderPrixPropriete']"));
        //priceValue = Integer.parseInt(hiddenPriceLocator.getAttribute("value"));
        WebElement plusButton = driver.findElement(By.id("PrixProprietePlus"));
        for(int i=0; i<2;i++){
            plusButton.click();
            priceValue = Integer.parseInt(hiddenPriceLocator.getAttribute("value"));
            if(priceValue==500000){
                System.out.println("purchase price is 500000");
            }

        }

        WebElement downPlusButton = driver.findElement(By.id("MiseDeFondPlus"));
        downPlusButton.click();
        WebElement downHiddenPrice = driver.findElement(By.id("sliderMiseDeFond"));
        String downPrice=downHiddenPrice.getAttribute("value");
        int downPricevalue = Integer.parseInt(downPrice);
        System.out.println("Down payment is " + downPricevalue);

 code to check the visibility   


    if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='Amortissement']")).isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("Element is Visible");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Element is InVisible");
        }

        //To check Element Present


if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='Amortissement']")).size() != 0) {
        System.out.println("Element is Present");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Element is Absent");
    }

    //To check Enable
    if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='Amortissement']")).isEnabled()) {
        System.out.println("Element is Enable");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Element is Disabled");
    }
    /*WebElement drpAmortization = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@id='Amortissement']")));
    Select dropDownAmortization = new Select(drpAmortization);
    dropDownAmortization.selectByVisibleText("20 years");*/

    WebElement drpAmortization = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='Amortissement']"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    //executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", drpAmortization);
    executor.executeScript("window.document.getElementById('Amortissement').click()");
    Select dropDownAmortization = new Select(drpAmortization);
    dropDownAmortization.selectByVisibleText("20 years");

    }


}
```

amortization drop down element is having the issue

WebElement drpAmortization = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='Amortissement']"));

Comment: your code is bit big, can you remove the method 1 and some unwanted codes and only provide the code where you are facing the issue... You can also remove your assert conditions and all. Else kindly give me the url of the dropdown element. I will check .

Comment: yeah you can check for the amortization drop down for the below link https://ia.ca/mortgage-payment-calculator

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the html code of the page and the drop downs are not conventional select dropdown. Its a mere button like stuff. So the approach is below,

1. Click on the down arrow button:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='form_calculateur_versements']/div[4]//b")).click();
   ```

and now the options will be visible.

2. Select the option from the drop down:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='form_calculateur_versements']/div[4]//li[2]")).click();
   ```

I am selecting the second option from the drop down in the above code.

Similar approach will work work for all drop downs in the page.

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Amortization drop-down is not a standard select control, hence the xpath you have used will not work. Additionally, standard Webdriver APIs such as selectByVisibleText etc cannot be used for selecting values from such drop-downs. However, you can write your own custom generic method for selecting values from them, as shown below:

```
public static void selectText(String dropDownLabel, String value) {
  String showOptions = "//label[normalize-space(text())='" + dropDownLabel + "']/following::b[1]";

  driver.findElement(By.xpath(showOptions)).click();
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  String option = "//label[normalize-space(text())='" + dropDownLabel + "']/following::li[normalize-space(text())='"
          + value + "']";
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath(option))));

  driver.findElement(By.xpath(option)).click();
}
```

In the above code, after clicking on drop-down, Webdriver will wait for drop-down options to appear and then click on desired option. Let me know, if you have further queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

A few words about the Solution:

1. Inducing `ExplicitWait` without `ExpectedCondition` defeats the purpose of being Eplicit as in `wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);`, you may consider removing it.
2. The xpath `//div[@class='slider-handle min-slider-handle custom']` is not unique. You may consider to construct a unique xpath.
3. The xpath `//div[@class='slider-track-high']` is not unique. You may consider to construct a unique xpath.
4. You have imported `Dimension` Class from `java.awt.Toolkit;` instead you may consider to import `Dimension` Class from `org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;`
5. As per best programming practice you may consider eleminating all the `Thread.sleep();` and replace through `ExplicitWait`
6. The `Amortization` is a `Modal Dropdown` so you may consider to handle it properly.
7. You may consider to remove the unnecessary imports from your code block as `org.junit.Assert;` as it was never implemented.
8. Here is your own code with some minimal tweaks, which prints `Value selected from Dropdown is : 20 years` at the end of the program on the console.

   ```
   import java.util.List;

   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
   import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
   import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

   public class Q44226865_select_dropdown_list 
   {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
       {


       WebDriver driver;
       String innerhtml = null;
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");

       //approach 1 - to maximize screen in chrome
       ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
       options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
       driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
       driver.get("http://ia.ca/");
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-secondaire']//a[@data-utag-name='loans']")).click();

       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Mortgages')]")).click();
       JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
       js.executeScript("scroll(255, 644)");
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Calculate your payments')]")).click();

       WebElement priceSlideLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slider-handle min-slider-handle custom']"));
       WebElement slideTrack = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slider-track-high']"));
       Dimension sliderSize = slideTrack.getSize();
       int sliderWidth = sliderSize.getWidth();
       int xCoord = priceSlideLocator.getLocation().getX();
       System.out.println(xCoord);
       System.out.println(sliderWidth);
       Thread.sleep(10);

       Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
       builder.moveToElement(priceSlideLocator)
       .click()
       .dragAndDropBy(priceSlideLocator, xCoord+sliderWidth,0)
       .build()
       .perform();

       WebElement hiddenPriceLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sliderPrixPropriete']"));
       int priceValue = Integer.parseInt(hiddenPriceLocator.getAttribute("value"));
       if(priceValue==2000000){
           System.out.println("price value is 2000000");
       }

       String stylePercent = priceSlideLocator.getAttribute("style");
       if(stylePercent.contains("left: 100%")){
           System.out.println("slide is 100%");
       }

       priceSlideLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slider-handle min-slider-handle custom']"));
       slideTrack = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slider-track-high']"));
       sliderSize = slideTrack.getSize();
       //sliderWidth = sliderSize.getWidth();
       xCoord = priceSlideLocator.getLocation().getX();
       System.out.println(xCoord);
       Thread.sleep(10);
       Actions builder2 = new Actions(driver);
       builder2.moveToElement(priceSlideLocator).click().dragAndDropBy(priceSlideLocator,-(xCoord+sliderWidth),0).build().perform();
       System.out.println("slide BACK%");

       hiddenPriceLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sliderPrixPropriete']"));
       //priceValue = Integer.parseInt(hiddenPriceLocator.getAttribute("value"));
       WebElement plusButton = driver.findElement(By.id("PrixProprietePlus"));
       for(int i=0; i<2;i++){
           plusButton.click();
           priceValue = Integer.parseInt(hiddenPriceLocator.getAttribute("value"));
           if(priceValue==500000){
               System.out.println("purchase price is 500000");
           }

       }

       WebElement downPlusButton = driver.findElement(By.id("MiseDeFondPlus"));
       downPlusButton.click();
       WebElement downHiddenPrice = driver.findElement(By.id("sliderMiseDeFond"));
       String downPrice=downHiddenPrice.getAttribute("value");
       int downPricevalue = Integer.parseInt(downPrice);
       System.out.println("Down payment is " + downPricevalue);

       if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='Amortissement']")).isDisplayed()) {
           System.out.println("Element is Visible");
       } else {
           System.out.println("Element is InVisible");
       }

       //To check Element Present


       if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@id='Amortissement']")).size() != 0) {
           System.out.println("Element is Present");
       } else {
       System.out.println("Element is Absent");
       }

       //To check Enable
       if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='Amortissement']")).isEnabled()) {
           System.out.println("Element is Enable");
       } else {
           System.out.println("Element is Disabled");
       }

       WebElement drpAmortization = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='form_calculateur_versements']/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/b"));
       drpAmortization.click();
       List <WebElement> drpAmortization_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@id='form_calculateur_versements']//div[@class='selectric-scroll']/ul/li"));
       System.out.println("Number of Elements : "+drpAmortization_list.size());

       for (int i=0; i<drpAmortization_list.size(); i++)
       {
           WebElement my_element = drpAmortization_list.get(i);
           innerhtml = my_element.getAttribute("innerHTML");

           if(innerhtml.contains("20 years"))
           {
               Thread.sleep(3000);
               my_element.click();
               break;
           }
       }
       System.out.println("Value selected from Dropdown is : "+innerhtml);
     }

   }
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.